# consume API from node JS

Tags: node.js, api, backend

How would I consume any API from my backend in node JS.
Let's say that I want to make only use of a few routes but that they do not hit the API from the frontend but that the response is made by the backend that previously has already developed that query logic.

Comment: Are you asking how to initiate a HTTP request from your node.js to the same server? So a sort of internal request?

Comment: What kind of API?

Comment: no special API, jsonplaceholder for example.
My idea would be to hit the route 'users' where I only have the names and the id in my bakend (node ​​js) and then the frontend makes the query to my backend and not jsonplaceholder

Comment: You could put a proxy in front that goes to 1 server for certain routes, and another server for other routes

Comment: Your question is not very clear on the requirement. Please elaborate more, better you can provide example.

Comment: If you mean how to do you make calls to an external http -based API from your nodejs program, then you would use a library built for making http requests.  You can use the built-in `http.request()` or you can use a higher-level library (generally easier to use) such as `got()`, `axios()`, `node-fetch()` or `superagent()`.

Comment: Thanks people! :)